# create a numpy array of zeros with same dtype as another array but different shape

Tags: numpy

How can I create a NumPy array f zeros with the same dtype as another array?
I know about `zeros_like()` but it gives the same shape as the passed array. I am looking for a different shape but the same dtype as the source array.

Comment: use the `np.zeros` function

Comment: `new_array = np.zeros(new_shape, dtype=source.dtype)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NumPy array's have a attribute called `dtype`. Simply use this attribute when creating a new array with the same data type.

```py
a = np.array([0,1,2])
print(a.dtype) # dtype('int64')
b = np.array([3.1,4.1,5.1], dtype=a.dtype)
print(b) # array([3, 4, 5])
```